# Java Camera Implementation

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

I'm trying to implement a camera feature for a game, in order to basically extend the playing field for the player, horizontally for now. I have only made a camera class once before, but a problem I always come in contact with is either the camera's positions work but translate() in Graphics doesn't do anything or the player is unable to move. I've tried several different solutions and suggestions, but am unable to figure out what the problem is. Here is the most basic code:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{       
    public GamePanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(null);
        setOpaque(false);
        cell = new WBCell();
        addKeyListener(cell);
        camera = new Camera(cell);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        grabFocus();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.translate(camera.getX(), camera.getY()); 
        g2.drawImage(cell.getImage(), cell.getX(), cell.getY(), null);
        g.translate(-camera.getX(), -camera.getY());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Game.getCards().show(Game.getCardP(), "Start");
    }
```

Basic code for the camera to keep the player in the center of the screen:

```
public class Camera 
{
    private WBCell player;
    private int x = 0, y = 0;

    public Camera(WBCell wCell)
    {
        player = wCell;
    }

    public void cameraMove()
    {
        System.out.println("Cam: " + x + ", " + y + "\t\t" + (-player.getX() + Game.WIDTH/2) + ", " + (-player.getY() + Game.HEIGHT/2));
        x = -player.getX() + Game.WIDTH/2;
        y = -player.getY() + Game.HEIGHT/2;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
}
```

For reference the cell object or WBCell class just loads a BufferedImage and slaps it on the panel once drawImage() is called. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess You need to use ARkit, did you try that?

Comment: Why would I need to use that @Zich? It's possible to implement a camera into java, I've done it before without any special kits or software, but I can't figure out how to do it now?

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be wrong there. In general, `Graphics2D#translate` does what it is supposed to do, so something else must be wrong. What does  debugging (in doubt, by adding a `System.out.println("Translate by "+camera.getX()+","+camera.getY()); ` before the `translate` call) print?

Comment: @Marco13, sorry for the late response. As I said above the coordinates printed seem to be right, but then it never translates, and sometimes I am unable to move the player class at all.

Comment: Sorry, the current code is not sufficient in order to figure out what is wrong there. You could try to create a [MCVE] , but until now, one could only guess...

Comment: @Marco13, I thought this was good enough for a minimum verifiable example. I didn't want to perform a code dump, so I just gave the basic code which I know causes the problem, and explained what was going on? Please do elaborate on what else I could add to make it a better example, in terms of what other code would be necessary or if the explanation was too broad.

Comment: Well, the point is: I could now add some boilerplate/dummy code so that I can compile and run it. But I **KNOW** that `Graphics2D#translate` works. So it's not entirely clear what an answer could look like. Are you really printing the coordinates in the `paintComponent` method, as suggested above? (If *nothing* moves, then this might be because you accidentally created two `Camera` instances ... who knows...)

Comment: I'm printing the coordinates in paintComponent and every time the player moves the coordinates do change, which should be happening. As for 2 cameras, I only put new Camera inside the constructor, which is only called once, so I don't think that should be happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my camera looks like:

```
x = (player.getX()+(player.getWidth()/2)) -           game.getWidth()/2;
y = (player.getY()+(player.getHeight()/2)) - game.getHeight()/2;

g2d.translate(-camX, -camY);
 //render everything(including player)
g2d.translate(camX, camY);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out my error shortly after and redesigned the way the camera actually follows the player. In addition, in this previous attempt, I believe that I forgot to render everything in between the 2 translate methods, which caused most of the problems. All good now though.

Comment: Great to hear!!